# Can I wear techeilet on only one corner?

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

I'm fixing someone's tallit, with the on one corner strings ripped. I have time to replace only one corner per week. (I would do subsequent corners in subsequent weeks.) I could either replace it with all-white strings, as is current, or replace with techeilet.

Would a tallit with just one corner (or two, or three) with techeilet be valid, in the intervening time? Would there be halachic issues such as bal tigra?

Comment: Is he wearing it in the interim? Is there any rule that tzitzis should be done in one shot? What about someone who made tzitzis and does only one corner per week and the others are empty? Why is techeiles relevant?

Comment: Yes, wearing it in the interim.  Only one corner is pasul and I would start with that.  Someone who began with one white corner and left the others blank wouldn't fulfill,  I think.  Here there would be four filled kosher corners,  but only one with techelet

Comment: Isn't this exactly התכלת אינה מעכבת את הלבן?

Comment: Plus one.  But that just means that one still fulfills something without any techelet. Not addressing a mixture. Maybe if techelet is there,  it need be on every corner or else it seems like a shita of only one kanaf (that is venatnu al tzitit hakanaf petil techelet ). Seems saduceean, maybe bal tigra

Comment: DoubleAA is correct on this. As you have described, it would not pose a problem. You can replace the remaining 3 corners when you have the opportunity.

Comment: From what I've seen, majority opinion and practice of Jews is not to wear so-called t'cheilet (I know the t'cheilet people will disagree, but outside their bubble this is true.)  So if he does not have it on now, don't replace it without asking his opinion. Very likely his Rabbi is against adding t'cheilet, (as per Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky shlit"a) or at the very least holds there is not point (as per Rav Elyashiv, Rav Asher Weiss, Rabbi Reisman and others.)

Comment: Neither I, he, or his rabbi are against adding (real) techelet,  and I have his consent.